# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I'm new to this PHP and MySQL world. I've been given an assignment about simple system. But i got this error and i don't know how to fix it. Hope you guys can help me.

```
<?php
            include ("config.php");

            mysql_select_db("dbpelanggan") or die(mysql_error());
            echo "Sambungan ke pangkalan data berjaya!";

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pelanggan") or die(mysql_error());  

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
            { <table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID Pelanggan</th>
                    <th>Nama Pelanggan</th>
                    <th>Kod Pelanggan</th>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    echo ".$row['idPel'].;
                    echo ".$row['NamaPelanggan'].;
                    echo ".$row['KodPelanggan'].;
                </tr>
            </table>
            }
            ?>
```

and the error is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp2\htdocs\LI\Assignment1\proses_simpan2.php on line 10
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You should learn basics before asking for this type of errors...

Comment: All html needs to be outside `<?php ?>` tags!

Comment: Yeah, sorry Debflav. But i need a guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have errors in your code.. many errors. The following code works

```
<?php
            include ("config.php");

            mysql_select_db("dbpelanggan") or die(mysql_error());
            echo "Sambungan ke pangkalan data berjaya!";

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pelanggan") or die(mysql_error());  
        echo '<table width="70%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">'
        . ' <tr>
                <th>ID Pelanggan</th>
                <th>Nama Pelanggan</th>
                <th>Kod Pelanggan</th>

            </tr>';
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )){ 
               echo"<tr>
                <td>".$row['idPel']."</td>
                <td>".$row['NamaPelanggan']."</td>
                <td>".$row['KodPelanggan'].
             "</td></tr>";

             }
             echo "</table>";
            ?>
```

Comment: OK. start of '<table>' should be outside of loop. it creates a new table for evary row in loop. Correct answer has it inside the loop.

Comment: is that how you need?

Comment: now the data in the database can be view on screen, Srihari.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

**`HTML`** code cannot call together with **`PHP`** code. You need to open and close **`PHP`** every time before you try to start your **`HTML`** code and open your **`PHP`** code after **`HTML`** code every time before you try to start **`PHP`** code after **`HTML`**.

```
<?php
                include ("config.php");

                mysql_select_db("dbpelanggan") or die(mysql_error());
                echo "Sambungan ke pangkalan data berjaya!";

                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pelanggan") or die(mysql_error());  

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
                { 
    ?> //you need to close php here

    <table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID Pelanggan</th>
                        <th>Nama Pelanggan</th>
                        <th>Kod Pelanggan</th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <?php // open php here
    echo $row['idPel'].$row['NamaPelanggan'].$row['KodPelanggan'].;
    ?> //close php here
                    </tr>
                </table>
    <?php //open php here
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix `PHP` & `HTML`. You need something like this in your `while` loop:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
            {  
echo '<table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID Pelanggan</th>
                    <th>Nama Pelanggan</th>
                    <th>Kod Pelanggan</th>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['idPel'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['NamaPelanggan'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['KodPelanggan'].'</td>
                </tr>
            </table>';
            }
```

---

**Note**

As all the other answers posted after mine just copy pasted, they didn't realise that the OP was missing `<td>`'s for each of the echo values.

Comment: @shira That's okay mate, just remember that HTML and PHP do not mix like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open and close the php when you want to have some HTML code. So in your case you will have something like this:

```
<?php
        include ("config.php");

        mysql_select_db("dbpelanggan") or die(mysql_error());
        echo "Sambungan ke pangkalan data berjaya!";

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pelanggan") or die(mysql_error());  

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {  ?>
            <table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
            <tr>
                <th>ID Pelanggan</th>
                <th>Nama Pelanggan</th>
                <th>Kod Pelanggan</th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <?php echo $row['idPel']; ?>
                <?php echo $row['NamaPelanggan']; ?>
                <?php echo $row['KodPelanggan']; ?>
             </tr>
        </table>
        <?php 
        } 
     ?>
```